# OnClick insert top at the element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a top element when i click in the link

I try to do this on js, but is not working:

```
$(function test() {     
var newtop = $('.plugin-noticias').position().top + 100;
$('.plugin-noticias').css('top', newtop + 'px');
});
```

And this on the link:

```
<a href="#" onclick="test()"><img src="img/seta-cima.png" alt="Setas" /></a>
```

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add 100px to the top using jquery, you don't have to calculate it yourself.

```
function test(){
    $(".plugin-noticias").css({
        top: "+=100px" 
    });
}
```

Also, your code has syntax errors. You don't have to wrap every function in a jquery function.

Answer (score 0):

You are using online function call. The function must be declare before your browser reach the `onclick=` line.

Unwrap you function from the DOM ready and put it in the head.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to call the function from the onclick attribute (would be better to bind it in jquery imo) then it should be declared like this so that it is in the correct scope:

```
function test() {     
    var newtop = $('.plugin-noticias').position().top + 100;
    $('.plugin-noticias').css('top', newtop + 'px');
}
```

What I would actually do is:

```
<a href="#" id="test"><img src="img/seta-cima.png" alt="Setas" /></a>

$(function() {
    // bind the click event using jquery
    $('#test').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // stop the link click 
        var newtop = $('.plugin-noticias').position().top + 100;
        $('.plugin-noticias').css('top', newtop + 'px');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is:

```
$(function() { 
    window.test = function(){    
        var newtop = $('.plugin-noticias').position().top + 100;
        $('.plugin-noticias').css('top', newtop + 'px');
    }
});
```